# How does the signup process work in socialengine? How/What and when is code called

Tags: php, mysql, networking, socialengine

I'm working on modifying a copy of social engine so that the sign up process includes an initial survey. I've already got a view, drawn my form however I'm not sure where the logic is processed. I know there are methods inside the corresponding controller but I'd like to save the data once the entire of the sign up process has finished.

Can anyone give me an overview of how the sign up process works in terms of MVC structure and communication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for future reference I've added a blog post that I've created about this subject. It essentially boils down to creating new plugins/views/forms and editing the database in the engine4_user_signup table.

See the full post below for a more in depth discussion

http://garbtech.co.uk/socialengine-modify-sign-up-process/

Answer (score 2):

Each plugin saves the data to the session on submit. Once the user finishes going thru the steps, the session should now contain all valid data. A transaction is then created, and all data is saved to the database. Thats basically how it works.

Of course the plugins can get a bit complicated if you are creating one. I created one myself and it took me a few days. Even then I didnt 100% understand the process, but I believe Ive got it down pretty good now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add an extra step in the signup process. For this you need to create a new signup plugin. Take a look at this table- `engine4_user_signup`, you can see the plugin classes listed here. The classes are located in this folder- `\application\modules\User\Plugin\Signup`, you have to create a new one here. If you go through these classes you'll probably have an idea how to do what you are looking to do.